# Regex Expression Special Characters

Tags: c#, regex

The code is in C#. 
If I use in regex simple string the code is working (for example fileName="Test"), but if I use special characters(- ( ) [ ] {} ! . , ` ~ @ # % ; = - + &) appear problems.

```
fileName = "Test- ( ) [ ] {} ! . , ` ~ @ # % ; = - + &"; 
string pattern = ".*" + fileName + @"_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}.xml";
//pattert = ".*" + "Test- ( ) [ ] {} ! . , ` ~ @ # % ; = - + &" + @"_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}.xml";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

if (rgx.IsMatch("..\\"+"Test- ( ) [ ] {} ! . , ` ~ @ # % ; = - + &_13_45_23.xml"))
{
...
}
```

There are chances to use these special characters. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to escape all characters inside `fileName`, before concatenating it into `pattern`. See @L.B's solution to this.

Comment: Condition in if(..) to be true. In if(..) to match rgx with "..\\"+"Test- ( ) [ ] {} ! . , ` ~ @ # % ; = - + &_13_45_23.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method if you want to safely handle special characters in `fileName`, for example:

```
string pattern = ".*" + Regex.Escape(fileName) + @"_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.xml"; 
//                            and don't forget to escape the '.' here ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Regex.Escape`

```
filename = Regex.Escape(filename)
```